# Dynamics Business Central (Create Item with Location via API)

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I have successfully created items via the API of Business Central.

However, I was just told that the location is going to be required when creating items and I am having issues with this. Is there a way for me to create items with Location Codes? I dont see this option in the documentation of Business Central.

For reference, this is the json body of the request.

```
{
    "number": "1896-S",
    "displayName": "ATHENS Desk",
    "type": "Inventory",
    "itemCategoryId": "e21a6a90-44e3-ea11-bb43-000d3a2feca1",
    "itemCategoryCode": "TABLE",
    "blocked": false,
    "gtin": "",
    "unitPrice": 1000.8,
    "priceIncludesTax": false,
    "unitCost": 780.7,
    "taxGroupId": "9f196a90-44e3-ea11-bb43-000d3a2feca1",
    "taxGroupCode": "FURNITURE",
    "baseUnitOfMeasureId": "5ca6738a-44e3-ea11-bb43-000d3a2feca1",
    "baseUnitOfMeasureCode": "PCS"

}
```

I have tried adding inventory value but it is spitting out an error that says location code is required.

Answer (score 0):

*It took some R&D to let me know that the request body that can be found in Microsoft Document actually contains some wrong property name. we can go to [https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/[your](https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v1.0/%5Byour) domain]/api/v1.0/$metadata where after authentication we get the XML that specifies the property names that should be used. So, the request body that i found working is:*

```
{
  "number": "1836-S",
  "displayName": "ATHENS Desk",
  "type": "Inventory",
  "blocked": false,
  "baseUnitOfMeasure": {
    "code": "PCS",
    "displayName": "Piece",
    "symbol": "",
    "unitConversion": null
  },
  "gtin": "",
  "itemCategory": {
    "code": "TABLE",  //make sure item category with this code doesn't already exists
    "displayName": "Assorted Tables"
  },
  "inventory": 0,
  "unitPrice": 1000.8,
  "priceIncludesTax": false,
  "unitCost": 780.7,
  "taxGroupCode": ""
}
```

Answer taken from here - [Create Item in Dynamics 365 Business Central using Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62469636/create-item-in-dynamics-365-business-central-using-rest-api)

Try that when you're logged in, it should hopefully give you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: I dont think its supported any longer. I tried the method above but it returned this message: {"error":{"code":"Authentication_InvalidCredentials","message":"Web service access key is no longer supported as authentication. Please use OAuth.  CorrelationId:  92c645de-ef9d-4cf6-946f-8201181bf177."}}

Comment: The error message you're getting says your authentication mechanism isn't supported. Get past that so you have permission to access the relevant URL and you should get what you need.